# How To Read Request Payload With Content Type Is application/octet-stream In Python?

Tags: python-requests, request, metamask, web3py, decentralized-applications

I'm trying to send request to this website https://game.elemon.io/02.17/ to simulate login action,  I found request login but the Request Payload seems to be application/octet-stream content type, I can't read it so I don't know which key and value I should use to implement this login action (I have session). Please help me (please look at picture below for more detail)
P/s : this is a gamefi web, so I manually login by metamask wallet

[image]

[image]

[image]